# JavaScript/jQuery - ordering of element arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using `document.getElementsByClassName("some_clas_name")` or `$(".some_class_name")` in JavaScript and jQuery, respectively, all of the elements with the target class name become available as an array of objects.  What is the default order by which HTML elements are sorted when they are put into arrays? In other words, on what criterion does JS/jQuery base its ordering of HTML elements, assuming the elements are of the same type?

Comment: document order as found when using a depth-first traversal of the DOM.

Comment: @squint Thanks, makes sense.